# Can't link to the new added site that is under the same IP with other sites using phalcon framework

Tags: php, phalcon

I want to put a demo site in `/var/www` with other sites that were developed using `Phalcon` framework by another developer.

Those Phalcon sites can be linked through only IP address eg.192.168.x.xx. But when I put my demo site with these Phalcon sites, and tried to link to my demo site by typing `'192.168.x.xx/demo/'`, the page show `'DemoController handler class cannot be loaded`'.

The demo site is just a 'Hello world' site from phalcon tutorial. I know the basic operation of phalcon structure, but cannot figure how this work. If you need any codes or further information to see where the issue is, just ask me and I will provide it.

The server is under Linux.

Comment: Can you share your directory structure and server information?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your baseUri.

Read this example.

https://docs.phalconphp.com/bs/3.2/url#base-uri